# How do I get xml data into php array in TCP/IP socket?

Tags: php, xml, sockets

Can anyone give me solution about storing xml data in php array. I have taken data in
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
but its not converting into php array when I tried simplexml_load_string($result),Its shows me

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/socket.php on line 115
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/socket.php on line 115
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/socket.php on line 115

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried looking at `$result` to see what value it actually holds?

Comment: Yes, I tried print_r($result), I prints the xml data.

Comment: I'm getting bool(false) output when I tried                                                       $doc = simplexml_load_string($result);     var_dump($doc);

Comment: I have done it through :                                                                          $reply = "";
do {
    $recv = "";
    $recv = socket_read($socket, 2048);
    if($recv != "") {
        $reply .= $recv;
    }
} while($recv != "");
socket_close($socket);
$result = simplexml_load_string($reply);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);